# Dropdown Menu Item in React Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a `MenuItem` in my Dialog2 in my React app. I have a problem displaying the `MenuItem`. I already put a `zIndex: 1900` that is higher than the two dialogs. How come it doesn't appear on the front. It is hiding still on the back of the dialogs?

Pls check my codesandbox here:
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-dialog-menuitem-dropdown-xumpj)

```
<DialogContent style={{ width: 300 }}>
  <TextField variant="outlined" select label="Gender" fullWidth>
    {genders.map((gender, index) => (
    <MenuItem key={index} value={gender} style={{ zIndex: 1900 }}>
    {gender}
    </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </TextField>
</DialogContent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to target the `Menu` popover `z-index`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customMenuPopover: {
    // take note of !important because default z-index is applied inline
    zIndex: "1900 !important"
  }
});

<TextField
  SelectProps={{
    MenuProps: {
      PopoverClasses: {
        root: classes.customMenuPopover
      }
    }
  }}
  variant="outlined"
  select
  label="Gender"
  fullWidth
>
  {genders.map((gender, index) => (
    <MenuItem key={index} value={gender} style={{ zIndex: 1900 }}>
      {gender}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

[image: Edit Nested Dialog MenuItem Dropdown (forked)]

Comment: Great job! Thank you